# Add a link to an image or an caption

Tags: markdown, docusaurus

I'm writing a document in Docusaurus V2.

I understand (from [here](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/static-assets)) that we could insert an image by

```
<!-- reference static/img/docusaurus.png -->
![Docusaurus logo](/img/docusaurus.png)
```

Or

```
// reference static/img/slash-birth.png
<img src="/img/slash-birth.png" alt="docusaurus mascot" />
```

But now, I would like to add a URL to the image, such that clicking on the image or its caption could open the URL in a browser. Is it possible to implement this in Docusaurus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the standard html anchor tag

```
<a href=“www.google.com”>
<img src="/img/slash-birth.png" alt="docusaurus mascot" />
</a>
```

Comment: Are you sure it works? I tried `<Link to="http://www.google.com"><img src="/static/img/logo.svg" alt="mascot" /></Link>`, the image showed well, whereas the link did not work.

Comment: @SoftTimur change Link to a
      <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img src="/img/slash-birth.png" alt="docusaurus mascot" />
      </a>

Comment: Could you update your answer, then I will accept it?

Comment: Most valid HTML would be valid Markdown, so you can just fallback on HTML.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
[![Image](./img/docusaurus.png)](https://www.google.es/)
```